# LoopSelector for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I was trying to add `LoopingSelector` but every time I get this error: `The type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelector' has no constructors defined`

Is there a way to add the `LoopingSelector` to a page in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ScrollViewer or FlipView
FlipView internally uses ScrollViewer.

In Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 ScrollViewer is very powerfull.
Use VerticalScrollMode and HorizontalScrolMode properties.
See [XAML scrolling, panning, and zooming sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-ScrollViewer-pan-and-949d29e9)